# Proper usage for form_dropdown() in CI

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to figure out why the disabled attribute is not getting applied to my dropdown. As far as I know I'm applied the correct attributes to the form_dropdown function.

```
<?php if (in_array('No Wrestlers In Database', $allies)) {
$attributes = array('disabled' => 'disabled');
    echo form_dropdown( 'ally1', $allies, $attributes);
}
else {
    echo form_dropdown( 'ally1', $allies, $alliesList->ally1ID);
} ?>
```

Rendered HTML:

```
<select name="ally1">
    <option value="0">No Wrestlers In Database</option>
</select>
```

Comment: view source, is the html what you expect?

Comment: well that points to the php being wrong then.

Comment: @Dagon: http://i3.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/original/000/210/119/+_2acc5a8841f8752904d37f90a8014829.png

Comment: @Truth, well the op did not !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html) the third parameter is a string for the default selected item and the fourth is a string of attributes, not an array.

```
echo form_dropdown('ally1', $allies, 'default', 'disabled="disabled"');
```